# Python GDALwarp cut a raster with a shapefile polygon

Tags: python, raster, gdal, polygon, clip

I am trying to create a program that cuts multiple rasters in different folders with gdalwarp, the program works for square shapefiles but when I enter one with a polygon the program does not cut anything or create any image. How can I make this work?

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os
import shutil

carpetas=r'.../Pruebas/imagenes'
carpeta=os.listdir(carpetas)


output=r'.../Pruebas/output'
shp=r'.../Limite_ZE/nuevolim.shp'


for i in carpeta:    


    archivos=os.listdir(carpetas+'/'+i)
    dato_salida=os.mkdir(output+'/'+i+'_cut')

    for x in archivos:


        if '_B8' in x:
            continue

        elif x.endswith('.TIF'):

            options=gdal.WarpOptions(dstAlpha=True,multithread=True,cutlineDSName=shp,cropToCutline=True)


            outimage=gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab=carpetas+'/'+i+'/'+x,
                           destNameOrDestDS=output+'/'+i+'_cut'+'/'+x,
                           options=options)

            outimage=None


        elif x.endswith('.txt'):
            shutil.copy(carpetas+'/'+i+'/'+x, output+'/'+i+'_cut'+'/'+x)


print('Ya termine =)')
```

Comment: Two possibilities spring to mind, the first is CRS, are both your raster and mask shape in the same coordinate reference system? The second is a bad geometry for the polygon, does the cutline work using GDALWarp from the command line?

Comment: Hi Michael, they are in the same CRS, and I will try to create another shapefile to check that it is not damaged, but the truth is that this shape is done in the same way as the square shape with which the program works

Comment: This might help https://docs.qgis.org/2.14/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_geometry_checker.html

Comment: Oooooomg!!!! Michael you are amazing, you were right my shape file was damaged